# Pytorch LSTM - Training for Q&A classification

Tags: lstm, pytorch

I'm trying to train a model to classify if an answer answers the question given using this [dataset](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52419).

I'm training in batches and using [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) word embeddings. I train in batches of 1000 except the last one. The method I'm trying to use is to first giving the first sentence (question), and then the second sentence (answer) to LSTM and have it give me a number between 0 and 1 by using sigmoid function.

The problem is, loss always repeats itself after epoch 1. It never converges to the correct result which is if the answer belongs to the question, 1, 0 otherwise.

My code is as below:

```
class QandA(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
        super(QandA, self).__init__()

        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = 1
        self.bidirectional = True

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, self.hidden_size, num_layers = self.num_layers, bidirectional = self.bidirectional)
        self.lstm.to(device)
        self.hidden2class = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size * 2, 1)
        self.hidden2class.to(device)

    def forward(self, glove_vec, glove_vec2):
        # glove_vec.shape = (sentence_len, batch_size, 300)
        output, hidden = self.lstm(glove_vec)
        output, _ = self.lstm(glove_vec2, hidden)
        # output.shape = (sentence_len, batch_size, hidden_size * 2)
        output = self.hidden2class(output[-1,:,:])
        # output.shape = (batch_size, 1)
        return F.sigmoid(output)
model = QandA(300, 60).to(device)
loss_function = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
```

Is my approach so wrong that it can't work in practice? Or is there any other problem that I'm overseeing?

edit: Extra code regarding the training;

```
batch_size = 1000
# load_dataset loads the data from the file.
questions, answers, outputs = load_dataset()
N = len(outputs)
losses = []
for epoch in range(10):
    for batch in range(math.ceil(N / batch_size)):
        model.zero_grad()

        # get_data gets the data from the dataset (size batch_size, sequence batch)
        input1, input2, targets = get_data(batch, batch_size)

        class_pred = model(input1, input2)
        loss = loss_function(class_pred, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in NLP but from the code you have given, my first suggestion would be to lower the learning rate to maybe `lr=0.001` or even `lr=0.0001` and try it again as Adam usually requires smaller learning rates than vanilla SGD.

Comment: @Jan I tried changing the lr as you suggested, here are the [results](https://imgur.com/a/07g59pK), I don't think it changed anything. But the loss looks more organic now which I guess is a good thing.

Comment: How many training samples do you have in total? Have you tried *way smaller* batches (i.e. 16/32/64)? How about the distribution of samples? Is there an even distribution between correct answers (1) and incorrect answers (0)? Do you have training/validation/test splitting? Are the distributed evenly?

Comment: @dennlinger There are around 20k samples. I have not tried in smaller batches, I will do it now. The distribution is, q1-a1-0, q1-a2-0, q1-a3-1, q2-a1-0 and so on. The question repeats until the correct answer is given in the set (sometimes there might be more than one answer as well). So the correct answers are much more less than incorrect ones. I do have train/dev/test splitting, but I've not used dev or test samples yet because it looked like there was a problem in the training. The distribution is similar between splits.

Comment: What you could then try and do is to reduce the number of negative samples you are using, i.e. only use parts of the incorrect answers, to create an artificial balance between the classes. First make sure that you are in fact getting bad results due to this imbalance, though. One way to see this would be a confusion matrix.

Comment: @dennlinger I tried in smaller batches but the result was the same, and it also took much longer to train. When I made the confusion matrix, the result is like this, TP = 0, FP = 0, TN = 19320, FN = 1040. It always gives out 0 (I round the sigmoid output). I can try to eliminate some incorrect answers, see if that works.

Comment: How are you rounding values? Hard thresholding at 0.5? And yes, smaller batch sizes take longer to train, but eventually converge safer (and may even do so faster). Are you cutting of training after a certain period, or when you have reached convergence?

Comment: @dennlinger Yes, I hard threshold at 0.5. I train around 10 epochs normally. I've yet to reach convergence. As you recommended, I randomly removed incorrect samples so that the correct and incorrect samples are balanced. With 100 epoch, lr=0.0001, 2061 samples it looked like [this](https://i.imgur.com/i6ayWIS.png). Also I don't shuffle the sample on each epoch, I just thought that that might be the reason why it repeats itself. And on this graph, it looks like loss is going down, even though it is slow, maybe I just need to train much much longer, I don't know if I'm right.

Comment: Maybe try and increase your initial learning rate to something like 0.001, and then continually decrease it (after every epoch, multiply it by, say, 0.99). I would highly encourage you to shuffle your training data, and let it run to convergence. 10 epochs might be far to little for your case; I have trained networks that converge after around 1000 epochs only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to encode question and answer independently and put a classifier on top of it. For example, you can encode with biLSTM question and answer, concatenate their representations and feed to the classifier. The code could be something like this (not tested, but hope you got the idea):

```
class QandA(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
        super(QandA, self).__init__()

        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = 1
        self.bidirectional = True

        self.lstm_question = nn.LSTM(input_size, self.hidden_size, num_layers = self.num_layers, bidirectional = self.bidirectional)
        self.lstm_question.to(device)
        self.lstm_answer = nn.LSTM(input_size, self.hidden_size, num_layers = self.num_layers, bidirectional = self.bidirectional)
        self.lstm_answer.to(device)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size * 4, 1)
        self.fc.to(device)

    def forward(self, glove_question, glove_answer):
        # glove.shape = (sentence_len, batch_size, 300)
        question_last_hidden, _ = self.lstm_question(glove_question)
        # question_last_hidden.shape = (question_len, batch_size, hidden_size * 2)
        answer_last_hidden, _ = self.lstm_answer(glove_answer)
        # answer_last_hidden.shape = (answer_len, batch_size, hidden_size * 2)

        # flatten output of the lstm, if you have multiple lstm layers you need to take only the last layers backward/forward hidden states
        question_last_hidden = question_last_hidden[-1,:,:]
        answer_last_hidden = answer_last_hidden[-1,:,:]
        representation = torch.cat([question_last_hidden, answer_last_hidden], -1) # check here to concatenate over feature size
        # representation.shape = (hidden_size * 4, batch_size)
        output = self.fc(representation)
        # output.shape = (batch_size, 1)
        return F.sigmoid(output)
```